# How cudaMalloc is internally implemented under Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: cuda

I would like to know how the allocation of a memory space in CUDA is implemented under Ubuntu Linux. In other words, how `cudaMalloc()` works internally under Ubuntu Linux? What are the system calls used for this function?

Comment: CUDA runs on three operating systems. Do you imagine they are all the same? And why do you need to know this anyway?

Comment: I need for Ubuntu OS.. Just how it works while allocating memory??

Comment: As far as I know, the code that implements `cudaMalloc` is not published.

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea, but I don't know why people are down voting you for asking. This is a true hacker (in the sense of a programmer at heart) question :)

Comment: I believe CUDA is closed source, so the implementation wouldn't be know. Perhaps look into OpenCL? It's the open-source alternative to CUDA, and looking at it's malloc implementation would probably give you some good info.

Comment: @Nathan: How is OpenCL open source? Point me to any vendors driver source for OpenCL, please?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Looking into it a bit more, I'm not sure if it's quite open source. I could have been incorrectly assuming it was from stuff I'd heard before and the name of it. I hope you find what you're looking for!

Comment: @Nathan: Here is a hint - OpenCL isn't open source. It is defined by an "open", multi-vendor supported standard, administered by Khronos who maintain a standard set of header files. But every implementation I am aware of is and proprietary. There might be some open source stuff like LLVM in use, but drivers and hardware level implementation of the APIs is totally closed.

Comment: @anu: if you really want to see operating system level operations when CUDA is running, use strace. This question is not at all clear (or answerable), and I have voted to close it.

Comment: @ all, thanks for your reply.. I will search for OpenCL and also trace CUDA operations.

Comment: @talonmies There are opensource implementations of OpenCL. Most of them in early stages. For example: `pocl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUDA is proprietary.  It's likely that CUDA driver implementation is the same or similar to OpenCL.
But while OpenCL specification is open the implementation is not necessary and NVIDIA OpenCL driver isn’t open .

It's possible that the implementation is as simple as the driver submitting a malloc command completely handled on the hardware side with the kernel driver communicating with the system to achieve unified virtual addressing and to determine what memory resides in VRAM. Probably the technical part at the software side is to avoid the allocation or defer it.

Looking into [pocl](http://pocl.sourceforge.net/) can give you some idea how things can look like. NVIDIA implementation can be very different though.